# SQLKATA ASP .NET CORE MVC 6 SETUP ISSUE

Tags: c#, sqlkata

Im having issue in setting up of my SQLKATA in ASP core 6 MVC , the sample code in Sqlkata website used startup.cs to properly set the compiler.  Now it  ASP Core 6 no longer use startup, but used program.cs w/c incompatible to the code use by sqlkata w/c is :

```
services.Add<QueryFactory>(() => {

    // In real life you may read the configuration dynamically
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(
        "Host=localhost;Port=3306;User=user;Password=secret;Database=Users;SslMode=None"
    );

    var compiler = new MySqlCompiler();

    return new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);

});
```

I used builder.Services , but it doesnt accept the Add option.. Any idea what the issue and what todo?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt accept"? Are you missing a `using` statement?

Comment: yes i do have using SqlKata.Compilers;
using SqlKata.Execution;

Comment: and i put this in program.cs builder.Services.Add<QueryFactory> ( ( ) => {

 // In real life you may read the configuration dynamically
 var connection = new MySqlConnection (
  "Host=localhost;Port=3306;User=user;Password=secret;Database=Users;SslMode=None"
 );

 var compiler = new MySqlCompiler ();

 return new QueryFactory ( connection, compiler );   but im getting a notification stating it Iservice collection does not contain a definition of   add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this answer my inquiry , it seems I missed the DI (Dependecy Injection) , this link solved the issue, instead on using Add , it should be AddTransient with some modification with code :[SQL Kata - Dependency Injection with .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73326864/sql-kata-dependency-injection-with-net-6)