# SQL Kata - Dependency Injection with .NET 6

Tags: c#, sqlkata

What is the updated recommended way to use dependency injection with SQL Kata in a.NET 6 web project?

The current SQL Kata documentation for this has not been updated for .Net 6. The older syntax in startup.cs is shown here: https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/setup#aspnet-core-di-container

```
services.Add<QueryFactory>(() => {

    // In real life you may read the configuration dynamically
    var connection = new MySqlConnection(
        "Host=localhost;Port=3306;User=user;Password=secret;Database=Users;SslMode=None"
    );

    var compiler = new MySqlCompiler();

    return new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<QueryFactory>((e) =>
{
    var connection = new MySqlConnection("Host=localhost;Port=3306;User=user;Password=secret;Database=Users;SslMode=None");
    var compiler = new MySqlServerCompiler();
    return new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct syntax. Curious, what is your opinion on AddTransient vs AddScoped in a web app for the SQL Kata connection? From what I can tell adding a dbcontext for entity framework using AddDbContext<> would create it as scoped by default. Any reason not to do it that way with SQL Kata?

Comment: @BrianW, this depends on how you set up your scopes. By default, a scope is bound to the lifetime of a single request. Singletons are bound to the lifetime of the application. Transients are bound to the lifetime of the widest scope of their ancestors. That being, if you inject a transient into a singleton, it will widen the scope of that instance, as a captured dependency. You can create your own scopes, that have whatever lifetime you life. Any Scoped dependencies you create will will be bound to the lifetime of that custom scope.